# What should I do if I want to skip paragraphs starting with "<<" and ending with ">>" while reading a .txt file using Python?

Tags: python

For example, if I have the following lines, I want to skip all lines between "<<" and ">>"

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
<<ccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a simple solution:

```
# Read your file
with open("content.txt") as f:
    # Remember if we are inside a paragraph
    inside_paragraph = False
    # Store lines that are not part of a paragraph
    output = list()
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")  # Remove trailing newline character
        if line.startswith("<<"):
            # We are starting a new paragraph
            inside_paragraph = True
        elif line.endswith(">>"):
            # We just cleared a paragraph
            inside_paragraph = False
        elif inside_paragraph:
            # We are in a paragraph, skip this iteration
            continue
        else:
            # This line does not start with "<<" and does not end with ">>"
            # Also, we are not in a paragraph, so let's store the line
            output.append(line)
    print(output)
```

Output:

```
['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbb']
```